# How to Use Override Virtual Methods Using Inherited Classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

### Problem

I want to override a virtual method using an inherited class.

### Example

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass
{   
public:
  void PressButton()
  {
    Nuke();
  }

  virtual void Nuke()
  {
    std::cout << "KABOOM" << std::endl;
  }
};

class BigNuke
{
public:   
  void Nuke()
  {
    std::cout << "MASSIVE KABOOM" << std::endl;
  }
};

class ChildClass : public BaseClass, public BigNuke
{
public:
  /*
  void Nuke()
  {
    std::cout << "MASSIVE KABOOM" << std::endl;
  }
  */
};
```

My main looks like this:

```
BaseClass().PressButton();
ChildClass().PressButton();
```

The output:

```
KABOOM
KABOOM
```

Now I know if my child class does not inherit from `BigNuke` and I uncomment out that nuke method, I get what I expect:

```
KABOOM
MASSIVE KABOOM
```

So how do I get the `MASSIVE KABOOM` out when inheriting from another class? The only way I see it is for `BigNuke` to inherit from `BaseClass` but I don't want this. In my real application I have many different base classes and many different types of big nukes, all of which can be mixed and matched.

Comment: Elaborate and why the downvote? It's a full example

Comment: Why would you expect `BigNuke::Nuke()` being called, unless you actually decide to do so in an overridden function in `ChildClass`?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the downvote either.

Comment: You can't do that, except if you make `BigNuke` a child class of `BaseClass` because since `BigNuke` and `BaseClass` are not related, their is no link between `BigNuke::Nuke` and `BaseClass::Nuke`. The only way would be to call `BigNuke::Nuke` in `ChildClass::Nuke`.

Comment: If you used CRTP in defining the base classes that call the polymorphic functions, they could easily call the correct ones even though inherited through a different path.  Alternately, CRTP could be used to override the virtual functions (to call the inherited version) with less total source than doing so in individual child classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is "impossible". Their is no such thing in C++ as "linked by name". Basically, your code is equivalent to:

```
class A {
public:
    void f () { g(); }
    virtual void g () { }
};

class B {
public:
    void h () ;
};

class C: public A, public B { };
```

And you want to access `B::h` in `A`, but `A` does not know anything about `B::h`. Changing `B::h` to `B::g` won't change anything since these are only names (and there is no such thing as dynamic binding in C++).

One way to do what you want is by overriding `C::g` and calling `B::h` in it:

```
class C {
public:
    virtual void g () { B::g(); }
};
```

If you have many class like `B` and `C`, you may want to use a template:

```
template <typename T>
class _C: public A, public T {
public:
    virtual void g () { T::g(); }
};

class C: public _C <B> { };
```